# Erro de overflow

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos

Boa tarde, estou tendo um problema com overflow na minha classe Locacao, não tenho nem ideia do pq ele está ocorrendo. Sou iniciante na área, ainda não tenho muita noção desses erros, alguém poderia ajudar?

Seguem as classes abaixo.

```
public class Cliente
{
    private int cpf, tel;
    private String nome,email;
    private Locacao[]locacao;
    public Cliente(int cpf, String nome, int tel, String email)
    {
        this.cpf=cpf;
        this.nome=nome;
        this.tel=tel;
        this.email=email;
        this.locacao=new Locacao[5];
    }

    public void setcpf(int cpf){
        this.cpf=cpf;
    }

    public int getcpf(){
        return this.cpf;
    }

    public void setnome(String nome){
        this.nome=nome;
    }

    public String getnome(){
        return this.nome;
    }

    public void settel(int tel){
        this.tel=tel;
    }

    public int gettel(){
        return this.tel;
    }
    public void setemail(String email){
        this.email=email;
    }
    public String getemail(){
        return this.email;
    }
    public float location(Locacao nova){
        float valor=0;
        int periodo=0;
        for (int i=0;i<locacao.length;i++){
            if(locacao[i]==null){
            locacao[i]=nova;
            periodo=(nova.getdiaTermino()-nova.getdiaInicio())+((nova.getmesTermino()*30)-(nova.getmesInicio()*30));
                if (nova.getcategoria().equals("Básico")){
                    valor=periodo*Locacao.basico;
                    break;
                }
                if(nova.getcategoria().equals("Luxo")){
                    valor=periodo*Locacao.luxo;
                    break;
                }
                if(nova.getcategoria().equals("Super luxo")){
                    valor=periodo*Locacao.spLuxo;
                    break;
                }    
            }
        }
        return valor;
    }
    public void checkSubst(Carros novo){
        for (int i=0; i<locacao.length;i++)
            if(locacao[i]!=null)
                if((locacao[i].getcategoria().equals(novo.getcategoria()))&&(novo.getano()<=locacao[i].getano())){
                    locacao[i].setcarro(novo);
                    break;
                }
    }
    public float checkCost(){
        float valor=0;
        int periodo=0;
        for(int i=0; i<locacao.length;i++)
            if(locacao[i]!=null){
              periodo=(locacao[i].getdiaTermino()-locacao[i].getdiaInicio())+((locacao[i].getmesTermino()*30)-(locacao[i].getmesInicio()*30));
                if(locacao[i].getcategoria().equals("Básico"))
                    valor=periodo*Locacao.basico;

                if(locacao[i].getcategoria().equals("Luxo"))
                    valor=periodo*Locacao.luxo;

                if(locacao[i].getcategoria().equals("Super luxo"))
                    valor=periodo*Locacao.spLuxo;
              break;
            }
        return valor;
    }
    public float checkTotalCost(){
        float valor=0;
        int periodo=0;
        for(int i=0; i<locacao.length;i++)
            if(locacao[i]!=null){
                if(locacao[i].getcategoria().equals("Básico")){
                    periodo=((locacao[i].getdiaTermino()-locacao[i].getdiaInicio())+((locacao[i].getmesTermino()*30)-(locacao[i].getmesInicio()*30)));
                    valor+=periodo*Locacao.basico;
                }
                if(locacao[i].getcategoria().equals("Luxo")){
                    periodo=((locacao[i].getdiaTermino()-locacao[i].getdiaInicio())+((locacao[i].getmesTermino()*30)-(locacao[i].getmesInicio()*30)));
                    valor+=periodo*Locacao.luxo;
                }
                if(locacao[i].getcategoria().equals("Super luxo")){
                    periodo=((locacao[i].getdiaTermino()-locacao[i].getdiaInicio())+((locacao[i].getmesTermino()*30)-(locacao[i].getmesInicio()*30)));
                    valor+=periodo*Locacao.spLuxo;
                }
            }
        return valor;
    }
    public int checkCar(String categoria){
        int qtd=0;
        for(int i=0;i<locacao.length;i++)
            if(locacao[i]!=null)
                if(locacao[i].getcategoria().equals(categoria))
                qtd++;
        return qtd;
    }
    public void imprimir(){
     System.out.println("Nome:"+nome);
     System.out.println("Cpf:"+cpf);
     System.out.println("Telefone:"+tel);
     System.out.println("Email:"+email);
     for(int i=0;i<locacao.length;i++)
        if(locacao[i]!=null){
            System.out.println("Dia de início:"+locacao[i].getdiaInicio()+"Mês de inicio:"+locacao[i].getmesInicio());
            System.out.println("Dia de término:"+locacao[i].getdiaTermino()+"Mês de término:"+locacao[i].getmesTermino());
            System.out.println("Modelo do carro:"+locacao[i].getmodelo());
            System.out.println("Placa do carro:"+locacao[i].getPlaca());
            System.out.println("Valor da locação:"+checkCost());
        }
    }
}


public class Locacao
{   
    private int diaInicio, mesInicio, diaTermino, mesTermino;
    private Carros carro;
    static int basico=120, luxo=160, spLuxo=210;


    public Locacao(int diaInicio, int mesInicio, int diaTermino, int mesTermino, Carros carro)
    {
        this.diaInicio=diaInicio;
        this.mesInicio=mesInicio;
        this.diaTermino=diaTermino;
        this.mesTermino=mesTermino;
        this.carro=carro;
    }
    public void setdiaInicio(int diaInicio){
        this.diaInicio=diaInicio;
    }
    public int getdiaInicio(){
        return this.diaInicio;
    }
    public void setmesInicio(int mesInicio){
        this.mesInicio=mesInicio;
    }
    public int getmesInicio(){
        return this.mesInicio;
    }
    public void setdiaTermino(int diaTermino){
        this.diaTermino=diaTermino;
    }
    public int getdiaTermino(){
        return this.diaTermino;
    }
    public void setmesTermino(int mesTermino){
        this.mesTermino=mesTermino;
    }
    public int getmesTermino(){
        return this.mesTermino;
    }
    public Carros getcategoria(){
        return this.getcategoria();
    }
    public int getano(){
        return this.getano();
    }
    public Carros getcarro(){
        return this.carro;
    }
    public void setcarro(Carros novo){
        this.carro=novo;
    }
    public String getmodelo(){
        return this.getmodelo();
    }
    public String getPlaca(){
        return this.getPlaca();
    }
}


public class Carros
{
    private String placa, modelo, cor, categoria;
    private int ano;
    public Carros(String placa, String modelo, String cor, int ano, String categoria)
    {
        this.placa=placa;
        this.modelo=modelo;
        this.cor=cor;
        this.ano=ano;
        this.categoria=categoria;
    }
    public Carros(String placa, String modelo, String cor, int ano)
    {
        this(placa, modelo, cor, ano, "Básico");
    }
    public String getPlaca(){
        return this.placa;
    }
    public void setPlaca(String placa){
        this.placa=placa;
    }
    public String getmodelo(){
        return this.modelo=modelo;
    }
    public void setmodelo(String modelo){
        this.modelo=modelo;
    }
    public String getcor(){
        return this.cor;
    }
    public void setcor(String cor){
       this.cor=cor;
    }
    public int getano(){
        return this.ano;
    }
    public void setano(int ano){
        this.ano=ano;
    }
    public String getcategoria(){
        return this.categoria;
    }
    public void setcategoria(String categoria){
        this.categoria=categoria;
    }
}
```

Comment: Poste o stacktrace do erro, ele indicia onde o erro esta acontecendo.

Comment: Seria o que aparece na janela quando dá erro? é esse aqui: java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at Locacao.getcategoria(Locacao.java:42) e repete duas milhões de vezes. Uso o bluej.

Comment: Esse mesmo, ele indica onde o erro começou acontecer

Comment: Eu tinha pedido no método getcategoria de Locacao o retorno em tipo carro, mas era String, porém, o erro não é só esse :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está na classe Locacao na função getCategoria:

```
public Carros getcategoria(){
  return this.getcategoria();
}
```

Acho que você queria fazer é o seguinte:

```
public String getcategoria(){
  return this.carro.getcategoria();
}
```

Comment: Esse método era pra retornar uma String, agora a pouco eu disse ali, foi falta de atenção mesmo. Muuuito obrigada por achar o erro! eu nunca mais programo com sono kkkk.

Comment: sempre é bom escrever seus get setters e métodos com letras Maiúsculas e minúsculas ex.: getCategoria() assim ficará bem mais legível